# How to Change the java versions in parasoft soatest 9.9?

Tags: parasoft

I am running my soatest 9.9 version with java 1.7. Now i have a requirement to run the java code (written in 1.8) using my soatest 9.9. I am getting problems with some or other versioning. What are the steps to follow to successfully change the java versions with out messing up things.

Thanks in advance,
Sravanthi

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to SOAtest with additional argument?

soatest.exe -Zjava_home "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8/"